# Get Value From Object List

Tags: linq, list, c#-3.0

I have a list of objects Employee

```
public struct Employee
{
    public string role;
    public string id;
    public int salary;
    public string name;  
    public string address;          
}
```

I want to get the object where the name and id property matches the condition.
I have tried using this:

```
List<Employee> EleList = new List<Employee>();
var employee=  EleList.Find(sTag => sTag.id == 5b && sTag.name== "lokendra");
```

This is pretty time consuming because the list size is between `20000-25000`.Is there any other way to retrieve the result. Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can speed this up by using an appropriate collection type, e.g. a Dictionary.

If the `id` of the `Employee` is unique, you can use it as the key in a dictionary of type `Dictionary<string, Employee>`. Searching would look like this:

```
Employee employee;
if(dict.TryGetValue("5b", out employee) && employee.name == "lokendra")
    // employee found
else
    // employee not found
```

Creating the dictionary would look like this:

```
dict = EleList.ToDictionary(x => x.id, x => x);
```

---

If it is not unique but reasonably focused (only a few employees with the same id), you can use it as a key in a dictionary of type `Dictionary<string, List<Employee>>`. Searching would look like this:

```
Employee GetEmployee(string id, string name)
{
    List<Employee> employees;
    if(!dict.TryGetValue(id, out employees))
        return null;
    return employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == name);
}
```

Creating the dictionary would look like this:

```
dict = EleList.GroupBy(x => x.id)
              .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

---

Please note:
In both cases, you should create the dictionary only once and not for every search. So basically, instead of `EleList` you should have the dictionary.

Comment: I have to match both name and id.So while converting to dictionary only one parameter can be used as a key..please help me if we can make composite key..

Comment: How to create the dictionary of the type you have mentioned.If the key is same then it would give error.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Note that instead of using a GroupBy + Dictionary, you could use ToLookup.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Indeed. But in that case `dict` would have to be of type `ILookup<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Yup. But it would actually make the lookup code really simple, as you don't need to check for the presence of the key first.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Right, it returns an empty enumerable instead of throwing an exception if the key is missing. I have to admit, I often forget about this interface. Mostly because you can only get an instance via `ToLookup`. I never understood why no implementation of it has been made public...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Furthermore, I don't find this information in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549314.aspx). Is it actually an implementation detail that it doesn't throw and what it returns instead?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Well, it's not *specified* to throw in the interface, which I'd have expected otherwise. But I agree it could be better documented. The documentation for `Lookup` itself does state this: "If the key is not found in the collection, an empty sequence is returned." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292716.aspx) - the implementation is public, but can only be constructed via ToLookup.

Comment: @  Jon Skeet and DanielHilgarth sir.Thanks a lot for the help..I still could not find lot about lookUp..The link does not show too much detailed information about it.

Answer (score 0):

showing what John Skeet in his comments to Daniel Hilgarth might envision

```
static ILookup<string, Employee> _employeeMap = EleList.ToLookup(x => x.id);

Employee GetEmployee(string id, string name)
{
    return employeeMap[id].FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
}
```

Comment: @ Firo. How would i use Lookup in my case where i want to match the name also along with the id.Please explain.

Comment: see the Method `GetEmployee` i posted. There the id is first matched (`[id]`) to prefilter the results which are searched for by the name (`x => x.Name == name`).

Answer (score -1):

You can try using Linq

```
yourList.Where(sTag => sTag.id == 5 && string.Equals(sTag.name, "lokendra", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```